# How do I install Radare2 on Windows?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, radare2

I am trying to get Radare2 installed on my Windows machine. I do have Windows Subsystem for Linux up and running if that changes things. I have tried the git technique from their website:

```
git clone https://github.com/radare/radare2
cd radare2
sys/install.sh
```

This did strange things depending on what I did. There are some comments headed with the # symbol that explain what's going on.

```bsh
#-----Here I clone the repo.
PS [*****] C:\Users\*****\AppData\Local\Programs> git clone https://github.com/radare/radare2
Cloning into 'radare2'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 81, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (81/81), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (71/71), done.
remote: Total 215078 (delta 27), reused 17 (delta 10), pack-reused 214997
Receiving objects: 100% (215078/215078), 117.53 MiB | 817.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (164658/164658), done.
Updating files: 100% (3934/3934), done.
#-----Here I cd into the new repo and run the install script.
PS [*****] C:\Users\*****\AppData\Local\Programs> cd radare2
#-----This next command opened a new window, which disappeared immediately.
PS [*****] C:\Users\*****\AppData\Local\Programs\radare2> sys/install.sh
#-----Calling bash and passing the script yielded some nice errors.
PS [*****] C:\Users\*****\AppData\Local\Programs\radare2> bash sys/install.sh
sys/install.sh: line 2: $'\r': command not found
: ambiguous redirect 4: 1
sys/install.sh: line 6: $'\r': command not found
sys/install.sh: line 11: syntax error near unexpected token `$'in\r''
'ys/install.sh: line 11: `      case "$1" in
#-----Here I fired up my WSL Ubuntu system and tried to run the script.
PS [*****] C:\Users\*****\AppData\Local\Programs\radare2> wsl
*****@DESKTOP-6L7K90U:/mnt/c/Users/*****/AppData/Local/Programs/radare2$ sys/install.sh
: not found.sh: 2:
sys/install.sh: 5: Syntax error: Bad fd number
*****@DESKTOP-6L7K90U:/mnt/c/Users/*****/AppData/Local/Programs/radare2$
```

At this point, I decided to try and use the Windows binary instead. I went to the [download page](https://www.radare.org/r/down.html) and downloaded the windows binary, then unpacked it into my AppData programs folder. I then opened that folder and double-clicked on `radare2.exe`. This made a quick blip on the taskbar like a window was trying to open, which also immediately closed.

At this point, I suspect errors in the source code for Radare2 are causing it to crash almost immediately. Is this the case? Or do I need to do something different to get this running?

**-----Solved-----**

I went and experimented a little, including installing to a Linux VM using the git clone method. I have found that the windows binary is the way to go for this. to use it, unpack the downloaded binary, then open CMD/PowerShell in the radare2 directory, then run `bin/radare2.exe` or `bin/r2.bat`. You will need to manually add these to the path, though.